# 'Like' statement not producing any results

Tags: ms-access, vb.net-2010

I have a products table where I am trying to search for a value a user enters via a textbox to get a products description, basically any product that might contain the word 'Bread' for example,and the results will be displayed in a combobox, yet my select statement yields no results. When i run the exact same query in access it shows the information so I am not sure if my issue in my code is with the syntax of my query,can someone maybe advise what I am doing wrong here please. I'm using MS Access, and vb.net 2010.

```
     Sub search_prod(ByVal cmb As ComboBox, ByVal searchval As String)
    searchval = Trim("'*" & searchval & "*'")
    con.Open()
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandText = "Select (Products.Product_Descr) From [Products] WHERE (Product_Descr LIKE " & searchval & ")"
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    Do While dr.Read
        cmb.Items.Add(dr.GetString(0))
    Loop
    con.Close()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Print the like query and run it in MS-Access application to see what is wrong

Comment: DAO and ADO has different wildcadrs. Try to replace "*" by "%" or vice versa

Comment: Hi WebDev and Sergey, thank you for the feedback, it works fine in MS Access, it produces the required output, but when I run it in VB it produces no output at all

Comment: Please add the **final** `CommandText` to your question.

Comment: Hi Andre, thanks for responding, please advise what the last CommandText is that you are referring to, as I am not too sure.